# Open Url handling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios4, nsurlconnection

I have a problem that I am opening the "http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/eft-feel-happy-fast/id474157386?mt=8" type of url on a table view didSelectrowIndexPath, then app store  open and user can download my app but the problem is that I want to go back to my application from the app store how is it possible can any one help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you open safari and leave your app, you cannot control what happens next. The user will return to your app when he/she chooses to.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use default browser of device,you can't come back from that. For this create new class and use webBrowser. By the help of this u stay in you app.....

Answer (score 1):

You can use SFSafariViewController class to redirect the links within your apps and make sure that the user doesn't leaves the app. Here is a tutorial on how to do it.

[SFSafariViewController Tutorial](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/32/3/how-to-use-sfsafariviewcontroller-to-browse-a-web-page/)

PS- It is written in swift.